# How can I extract values using named groups captured by a REGEX in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following input:

```
.....a whole bunch of stuff before....
The Key(s): FOO-1234, FOO-125, FOO-859
The Key(s): FOO-5364
.....a whole bunch of stuff after....
```

I need to be able to capture all those 4 keys e.g. *FOO-1234*, *FOO-125*, *FOO-859* and *FOO-5364*.

Currently I am using the pattern:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"The Key\(s\): ((?<key>FOO-\d+)(, )?)+");
regex.Match(input).Dump();
```

I would like to get the value for all the keys matched but even though the above matches the input but the `Group` property of the `MatchResult` does not seem to have the keys captured correctly.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: instead of using RegEx which it appears that you are not understanding it, try using the string.Split function its much easier until you get more familiar with RegEx

Comment: How is that helpful? I am specifically asking a question on `REGEX` I am not looking for a suggestion on alternative solution using `string.split`.

Comment: Ok then how about using [`Regex.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ze12yx1d(v=vs.110).aspx) instead?

Comment: @Quantic, I need to avoid allocation, the code will be executed in a hot path, creating string arrays is not an option.

Comment: What happens when you take `?<key>` away?

Comment: @Martin, the `?<key>` only specifies naming for the captured groups, inclusion or the exclusion of it does not make any difference. It's only there to allow using the `"key"` as an index to the captured groups instead of  numerical indexing.

Comment: If you want to avoid allocation, regex is not the way to go. Actually, String.Split and Regex are both really bad at this. Look into a dedicated csv parser. Not all of them will build arrays.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, CSV parser won't be able to handle this as the input is not necessarily comma separated. The current solution does the job for what we want to accomplish with minimal `GC` pressure and development effort. If I find an alternative with even less `GC` allocation and more elegant solution then I may revisit it at a later date.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it turned out I had to look at the `Caputures` instead of the `Groups`:

```
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(input))
{
    match.Groups["key"].Captures.Dump();
}
```

Comment: Was that it? Testing [here](https://regex101.com/) shows you at least need to escape the paranthesis in `Key(s)` otherwise you just create another capture group for "s".

Comment: Yes, you are right, I missed the escape when I was composing the question, I have updated it now.